# Why are you allowed to use a tap on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, water

This might be a stupid question, but I would still like an answer...

When we use a tap, aren't we shlepping water from the resevoir (a carmelis) into our homes (a reshus hayachid)? It would seem to be a proper maaseh and not grama. If the answer is that the pipes are a makom petur, that shouldn't make a difference, since the water doesn't rest in the middle. Even if the water would rest, it would still be subject to the Machlokes brought in SA 346:1. Perhaps the answer is that water is always considered to rest on the way, and we go like the lenient opinion?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is it not grama?

Comment: I'm asking about the issue of transferring the water, not the issue of causing electricity to work.

Comment: About grama, I'm not absolutely sure, but I thought that since it happens instantaneously, you can't call it grama. Also, the position of Chazon Ish and others is that any machine set up to work in a certain way isn't grama on Shabbos.

Comment: @Dovid but this is literally hasaras moneia

Comment: Well... isn't the בידקא ראשונה still an issue? Also, I'm not sure if  grama on Shabbos has the same parameters as רציחה or  נטילת ידים, since the overarching rule is מלאכת מחשבת אסרה תורה. I'm not claiming to know... just wondering.

Comment: [There are no stupid questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question). :)